# Web Scraping using bs4. What should I do if a string doesn't have a tag associated with

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I was using bs4 to do a web scraping. 
I have had not problem getting the desired strings within tags, but it seems like there is one string that doesn't have any tags associated with (maybe I was wrong).

So the html format looks like this:

```
<li class='A'>
   <span class='B'> Some_string_here </span>
   " MY DESIRED STRING "
   <div class='C'> Some_string_here </div>
</li>
```

I know how to get the "some string here" but I have no idea how to get "MY DESIRE STRING"

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Could you post an example section of html?

Comment: Oh sure! This is my first time asking questions here and I'm sure I wrote the html example but somehow it didn't get posted..

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this:

```
>>> s = """
... <li class='A'>
...    <span class='B'> Some_string_here </span>
...    " MY DESIRED STRING "
...    <div class='C'> Some_string_here </div>
... </li>
... """
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> tree = BeautifulSoup(s)
```

using `contents`:

```
>>> tree.li.contents
['\n', <span class="B"> Some_string_here </span>, '\n   " MY DESIRED STRING "\n   ', <div class="C"> Some_string_here </div>, '\n']
>>> tree.li.contents[2].strip()
'" MY DESIRED STRING "'
```

using `strings` or `stripped_strings`:

```
>>> list(tree.li.stripped_strings)
['Some_string_here', '" MY DESIRED STRING "', 'Some_string_here']
```

using `find_all`:

```
>>> tree.li.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
['\n', '\n   " MY DESIRED STRING "\n   ', '\n']
```

and there are probably several other ways...

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it!                                            I also found another method from another post: tree.li.span.next_sibling